# Awk commands for each arg

Tags: bash, awk, for

I have an `awk` implementation in a bash script which I want to run for each
function arg using a do loop.  Each arg is composed of a multiline string.

```
for arg in "$@"; do

done
```

Here is the awk implementation which uses `<<< "$@"` to pass all function arguments.

What I want is to use each `arg` separately rather than pass all arguments together as with `"$@"`.

```
 awk '
   BEGIN {
     kl=0
     kmd="tput sgr0"
     rst = ( (kmd | getline outp) > 0 ? outp : "<" "sgr0" ">" )
     close(kmd)
     ka = "Wht 15 Grn 34 Blu 39 Ylw 11 Red 196 Amb 214"
     kb = "Cyn 51 Mgn 201 Syp 39 Code 39"
     ks = sprintf("%s %s", ka, kb)
     n = split(ks, kaggr)  # split makes kaggr start at index 1
     for ( i=1; i<n; i+=2 ) {
       knam = kaggr[i] ":"
       knum = kaggr[i+1]
       kmd=sprintf("%s%d\n", "tput bold; tput setaf ", knum)
       tseq[knam] = ( (kmd | getline outp) > 0 ? outp : "<" knam ">" )
       close(kmd)
      }
    }

   ## Detect keyword in index of array tseq, tseq[indx].
   ($1 in tseq) { kl=1 ; ctp=$1 ; next }

   /Rst:/ { kl=0 ; next }  # Reset colour rendition

   kl { print tseq[ctp] $0 rst }  # Print with specified colour
   !kl { print }                  # Use terminal text colour
' <<< "$@"
```

In previous work, I have encountered the problem of disappearing variables when having a loop that is in a pipeline. For further details, see [https:// mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024][1].

Although I think that for the case of pipelining to awk the problem of disappearing variables does not truly matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your loop is using `arg` as the loop variable and that you should be able to use `<<<"$arg"` to redirect the contents of this variable into your `awk` code:

```bash
for arg do
  awk '...as in the question...' <<<"$arg"
done
```

or, if you want to do more typing and remember to include the double quotes around `$@`,

```bash
for arg in "$@"; do
  awk '...as in the question...' <<<"$arg"
done
```

You could also pass the data on standard input with `printf`, which would make the loop POSIX-compliant (the `<<<` here-string redirection is not standard):

```bash
for arg do
    printf '%s\n' "$arg" | awk '...as in the question...'
done
```

All these loop variations would run the `awk` code once for each list element in the `"$@"` list, regardless of whether these are multi-line or not.

Note that I have not really looked at your `awk` code as the question is rather about the management of the input to the code.

Comment: I agree that what is in the awk part is not really so important.  I am starting to favour the use of process substitution with `awk '...' < <(printf '%s\n' "$arg")`.  What do you think of this ?

Comment: @Gibran It will have the same effect, but I'm no fan of this as a replacement for a simple pipeline from `printf` to `awk` as it adds complicated and non-portable syntax. In short, I'm not a fan of the syntax and I don't see a real benefit of using a process substitution here. Having said that, I wouldn't want to stop you from using whatever construct you want, if it makes more sense to you.

Comment: I have encountered the problem of disappearing variables when having a loop that is in a pipeline.  See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for further details.  Although I think that for the case of pipelining to awk does not truly matters.

Comment: @Gibran Yes, using a process substitution helps in the case where you need to read the output in a `while` loop _and have variables survive past the end of that loop_. You don't mention having this issue in the question though.

Comment: @Gibran Also note that in _that_ case, you would put the `awk` command in the process substitution, not the `printf` command: `while read ...; do ...; done < <(awk ... <<<"$arg")`. This seems quite unrelated to the current question though.

Comment: I do not see a problem for using the `awk` part in this case.  Should I worry about it when using `awk` ?

Comment: @Gibran I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: what would be the content of the read part?

Comment: @Gibran Sorry, what "read part". Are we still talking about your question? There is no mentioning of using `read` anywhere there.

Comment: Would calling awk using `printf '%s\n' "$arg" | awk '...'` suffer from the problem of disappearing variables.  Or could I use it without harm?.

Comment: I was talking about your `while read ...; do ...; done < <(awk ... <<<"$arg")`.

Comment: The FAQ you referenced describes the issue well and explains why it applies to `echo foo | while read; do var=bar; done; echo "$var"` (setting a shell variable in a subshell) which has nothing to do with `echo foo | awk 'script'` (no shell variables involved).

Comment: Right.  Then `printf '%s\n' "$arg" | awk '...'` should be good enough.